# Raspberry pi stuck on boot after edit config.txt

Tags: pi-2

I've edited config.txt, in particular `gpu_mem= 944` and now when I start the raspberry this is stuck on:

"A start job is running for dev-sda1.device (35 s / 1min 30s)"

what can I do?

PS: I can't use the console

Comment: What happens after the job times out after 1:30?

Comment: @TheDiveO I see a black screen

Comment: Hmm. This looks like a mounting job that has failed. Can you please cross-check your boot config.txt with a fresh config.txt?

Comment: @TheDiveO How can I do this? I can't access to the console..

Comment: The boot partitions containing config.txt are FAT, so you can even access them from a Windows systems. Or, flash another fresh mSD with Raspian, and boot this. Then plug in an mSD card reader into your Pi, mount the mSD, and compare /boot with /mount/pi/boot (or wherever you mount it to).

Comment: I believe you can hold down the shift key while booting, or use SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you Pi doesn't boot is because you have given **ALL** of the memory to GPU. **Why??**

Edit `config.txt` on another computer.